# rounding of values on mouse hover on histogram highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram using angular. The jsfiddle link below is for reference. Please note that i cannot round the actual data as that would not show the correct representation of data.

http://jsfiddle.net/x51b6pvs/52/

I need to round the data while on mouse hover on the bins. The range should show whole numbers that decimal values. How do I achieve that

angular code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EndingSurplus } from '../../../../api/dtos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ending-surplus-analysis',
  templateUrl: './ending-surplus-analysis.component.html',
})
export class EndingSurplusAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
    isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;

  @Input() results: Array<EndingSurplus>  = [];


  chartSeries: any[] =[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addSeries();
  }

  private addSeries() {


  this.results[0].data = [250137.3987,255384.7591,
269665.3148 ,
264750.7016 ,
251186.8573 ,
257117.2262 ,
246425.1166 ,
268831.1991 ,
259506.8683 ,
247144.4442 ,
265456.1009 ,
257710.1275 ,
268782.5507 ,
258241.7844 ,
270595.0334 ,
255264.26   ,
262818.6816 ,
258447.5023 ,
265164.3453 ,
245303.5167 ,
255826.28   ,
261484.0799 ,
257780.4357 ,
260216.1384 ,
272173.1936 ,
255860.7768 ,
251033.9228 ,
256528.2746 ,
244822.708  ,
265871.5068 ,
262955.2493 ,
273534.9778 ,
252979.7906 ,
252291.5207 ,
243097.5445 ,
249912.2    ,
278413.0176 ,
256562.7091 ,
257699.3842 ,
253676.1681 ,
259692.7011 ,
256805.0442 ,
254833.355  ,
265215.4941 ,
272812.6996 ,
263335.7108 ,
250751.507  ,
265420.264  ,
255219.6665 ,
258396.7417 ,
251339.0365 ,
263216.4245 ,
260058.4691 ,
255846.4635 ,
258073.6686 ,
261558.024  ,
273904.3493 ,
255078.906  ,
252440.9074 ,
252163.2524 ,
245073.8397 ,
265370.9981 ,
257230.9191 ,
266758.1989 ,
257282.1617 ,
265551.8811 ,
248172.3286 ,
257531.2419 ,
239070.8651 ,
248143.1465 ,
252949.2771 ,
270441.6692 ,
270588.7789 ,
254506.7736 ,
258616.974  ,
247716.1295 ,
261528.5313 ,
258288.2901 ,
255183.2629 ,
253631.8719 ,
252432.5228 ,
268209.3578 ,
246388.9813 ,
256646.549  ,
252458.1974 ,
252878.8888 ,
251977.9531 ,
257999.4554 ,
252156.805  ,
252017.968  ,
251062.3897 ,
263997.8646 ,
257363.3684 ,
264758.6442 ,
263441.2355 ,
247580.7156 ,
250322.836  ,
266294.9059 ,
268073.3878 ,
247838.6091 ,
261284.6835 ,
261446.966  ,
254107.9876 ,
244581.6138 ,
262860.4855 ,
251845.2552 ,
262251.9082 ,
263248.1984 ,
259764.5733 ,
260463.8964 ,
259949.1107 ,
263875.3178 ,
256891.0951 ,
269060.629  ,
251553.9578 ,
254182.872  ,
266582.7511 ,
250820.628  ,
250912.3719 ,
257221.106  ,
263006.5967 ,
254340.0253 ,
251565.7397 ,
252728.0205 ,
250957.1351 ,
262673.84   ,
254292.4379 ,
268748.9108 ,
265027.9924 ,
248583.6719 ,
259643.1074 ,
261429.4341 ,
245227.7857 ,
264736.9217 ,
252004.4496 ,
264158.9025 ,
263868.0186 ,
247871.0995 ,
263332.4629 ,
270297.1343 ,
266665.4826 ,
265627.388  ,
257075.9612 ,
256033.1819 ,
247036.805  ,
256518.9623 ,
269581.1533 ,
248356.7884 ,
258389.6549 ,
251481.712  ,
254849.6435 ,
263711.7374 ,
261068.4369 ,
251610.833  ,
260198.5526 ,
257179.4012 ,
254578.1473 ,
262704.0233 ,
259097.2433 ,
259529.9189 ,
265866.8621 ,
258291.739  ,
261266.086  ,
250460.1956 ,
267886.9146 ,
245178.0845 ,
266752.4659 ,
250777.3339 ,
268526.4688 ,
262195.0642 ,
254512.5036 ,
256020.5339 ,
265050.2764 ,
245706.5025 ,
254415.2112 ,
261613.4408 ,
247054.8881 ,
246784.2982 ,
245169.7241 ,
273565.4625 ,
266730.0278 ,
254053.4394 ,
256467.2487 ,
251037.9766 ,
255701.764  ,
256808.2518 ,
253740.9096 ,
262412.7946 ,
267146.48   ,
255252.5371 ,
255775.5357 ,
248252.7536 ,
251637.7299 ,
248903.624  ,
253705.0025 ,
255314.8475 ,
255035.3132 ,
247359.2354 ,
264645.8872 ,
263480.7112 ,
249350.0481 ,
253776.9345 ,
252893.239  ,
260790.2097 ,
258874.0023 ,
274887.6084 ,
272995.4317 ,
275359.2004 ,
256888.0142 ,
258682.2878 ,
242334.1288 ,
258026.2267 ,
258374.4818 ,
264386.7623 ,
255562.8709 ,
245785.093  ,
259974.2755 ,
271489.0142 ,
263555.3342 ,
255395.5071 ,
243197.082  ,
254640.3179 ,
257142.399  ,
272433.9963 ,
258482.9332 ,
268589.8874 ,
262445.3093 ,
256745.6688 ,
261459.5719 ,
274919.5275 ,
255815.4649 ,
263992.7056 ,
258826.737  ,
248632.9512 ,
273971.2736 ,
261288.7822 ,
255676.2591 ,
251099.1791 ,
244158.0126 ,
247788.432  ,
264962.6351 ,
266626.9525 ,
277859.2778 ,
240012.9569 ,
250884.7236 ,
255470.8729 ,
256258.2208 ,
247771.4848 ,
262735.6543 ,
255139.8657 ,
265649.7915 ,
266023.921  ,
266252.3258 ,
261619.95   ,
275232.7171 ,
253182.561  ,
261210.9162 ,
259868.9969 ,
261228.9504 ,
246733.5765 ,
258887.4544 ,
266458.0222 ,
252088.1486 ,
254289.8879 ,
259785.6685 ,
262101.3294 ,
251550.9125 ,
256313.0154 ,
261214.9333 ,
260626.3931 ,
249480.5819 ,
258934.5603 ,
250393.0402 ,
268108.3323 ,
267331.2422 ,
260331.0477 ,
255094.8563 ,
241748.1937 ,
243306.9024 ,
250237.5752 ,
256472.1966 ,
258554.9011 ,
262266.5877 ,
271532.172  ,
255434.477  ,
250639.97   ,
258803.7286 ,
256972.9055 ,
272722.9826 ,
266299.063  ,
260564.6397 ,
255576.2476 ,
249327.5022 ,
259178.1873 ,
259308.7373 ,
248379.5018 ,
265049.4156 ,
244542.7303 ,
257692.6787 ,
252899.0943 ,
256977.2088 ,
257587.0216 ,
263942.9705 ,
245455.2363 ,
258277.7107 ,
255080.235  ,
265520.1092 ,
270575.3339 ,
258273.3062 ,
253094.1083 ,
251095.0449 ,
266428.4918 ,
261129.281  ,
262640.1341 ,
272470.1974 ,
256482.0775 ,
252137.9066 ,
266352.3753 ,
242466.4639 ,
264230.8932 ,
267218.3372 ,
249285.0693 ,
265928.5015 ,
261597.6306 ,
258025.5476 ,
251966.9545 ,
255903.6029 ,
253764.2337 ,
274258.347  ,
250090.8219 ,
252702.8    ,
255766.3189 ,
246761.0289 ,
261058.6874 ,
263523.4418 ,
253133.0948 ,
272122.6176 ,
258424.0512 ,
266669.2285 ,
268018.4135 ,
256265.5016 ,
245142.6411 ,
246076.9411 ,
253642.3845 ,
262822.5327 ,
263626.6306 ,
260014.2615 ,
263406.6101 ,
260121.954  ,
268851.7686 ,
269378.4735 ,
260824.2916 ,
279751.9902 ,
261721.4696 ,
252502.3113 ,
270919.0078 ,
254080.6426 ,
246816.0595 ,
261003.9545 ,
256375.3541 ,
249961.9373 ,
250682.6824 ,
269665.8797 ,
260760.744  ,
254098.051  ,
249179.8821 ,
268889.0892 ,
244820.2889 ,
256135.3349 ,
246533.229  ,
255332.6997 ,
252170.5045 ,
259993.8169 ,
261580.219  ,
261261.2401 ,
262598.5298 ,
240005.6375 ,
248302.9663 ,
261290.7771 ,
256563.1091 ,
250809.8464 ,
265036.7385 ,
269105.1037 ,
261764.2819 ,
251658.1632 ,
248835.2238 ,
249906.9964 ,
260105.8262 ,
253676.3755 ,
250323.9677 ,
259620.5735 ,
262357.6164 ,
254577.5718 ,
269426.1775 ,
261023.7714 ,
253194.2553 ,
262892.868  ,
258129.0863 ,
256012.603  ,
251446.2645 ,
253767.6186 ,
266873.0938 ,
258042.4138 ,
259150.134  ,
271191.5042 ,
245409.8577 ,
271266.6853 ,
258022.5323 ,
255413.5033 ,
250359.7006 ,
250975.7614 ,
245022.7268 ,
265115.4689 ,
250574.2643 ,
258477.1707 ,
255542.2203 ,
262724.4621 ,
251840.9319 ,
255555.8949 ,
254894.8952 ,
255836.4834 ,
254888.8965 ,
258025.7877 ,
267293.1967 ,
252922.5218 ,
265073.6449 ,
262444.8769 ,
255502.5865 ,
249070.762  ,
252554.2335 ,
255794.5921 ,
247512.7796 ,
254100.482  ,
259049.6988 ,
270791.5189 ,
258364.7918 ,
254806.7354 ,
248829.1413 ,
249001.37   ,
265807.1597 ,
247618.6434 ,
261490.731  ,
249533.4528 ,
264014.0023 ,
251419.341  ,
264973.7203 ,
269347.4531 ,
266869.3733 ,
261370.9415 ,
264923.4046 ,
270042.4425 ,
259170.5331 ,
253792.6572 ,
261749.2593 ,
252425.0117 ,
255477.4187 ,
253825.0698 ,
258975.5508 ,
251869.3843 ,
246705.9526 ,
254382.106  ,
256289.5874 ,
263553.1111 ,
254432.3059 ,
270963.8814 ,
252048.2582 ,
253008.1217 ,
247552.2377 ,
258419.4645 ,
250716.9412 ,
254956.9422 ,
268298.8001 ,
264035.8603 ,
256245.2378 ,
249665.2363 ,
255563.3959 ,
251317.4839 ,
259465.3903 ,
255646.4284 ,
254282.9785 ,
254301.6776 ,
249865.9499 ,
248131.809  ,
250868.5572 ,
255907.1167 ,
257432.9346 ,
258733.8805 ,
258390.6775 ,
264400.2472 ,
258610.5291 ,
265480.8497 ,
250884.7388 ,
256788.6787 ,
255012.0214 ,
242164.6576 ,
256485.5519 ,
275845.0358 ,
249780.1743 ,
265808.7668 ,
269027.8704 ,
265102.0852 ,
264849.4939 ,
269983.4956 ,
251392.0016 ,
257253.8926 ,
253714.5631 ,
251857.6329 ,
262422.4803 ,
257206.127  ,
241112.8223 ,
256668.6921 ,
248766.4798 ,
248466.7834 ,
257003.5029 ,
250934.7782 ,
260725.6552 ,
273794.8858 ,
249535.5771 ,
255874.4263 ,
263510.9368 ,
241028.3849 ,
247120.5922 ,
262789.364  ,
259264.6337 ,
253422.9083 ,
277564.6972 ,
259210.4236 ,
251918.8446 ,
258946.2834 ,
263994.8378 ,
261868.44   ,
255835.4673 ,
242203.5154 ,
260900.0111 ,
265030.7866 ,
258666.2392 ,
252781.2586 ,
251818.401  ,
253631.3279 ,
247286.8826 ,
262242.2165 ,
251600.3774 ,
248949.5739 ,
259666.239  ,
253537.6107 ,
244189.0002 ,
263548.5289 ,
259468.8975 ,
274806.3949 ,
261794.1829 ,
250553.3847 ,
255896.9342 ,
259388.9225 ,
241808.2841 ,
256483.0838 ,
246738.702  ,
256422.1852 ,
260853.6245 ,
252824.8976 ,
249196.1878 ,
249903.5061 ,
259369.182  ,
256403.1491 ,
257382.2232 ,
257823.2392 ,
252059.7718 ,
265320.9555 ,
258349.4691 ,
261036.6308 ,
249994.9285 ,
254121.9117 ,
247393.1854 ,
249326.9166 ,
275192.8356 ,
256349.9036 ,
252284.8854 ,
254802.1104 ,
263954.8089 ,
256855.6284 ,
261349.0897 ,
264074.7967 ,
267636.9025 ,
256478.6563 ,
250846.3714 ,
251570.3274 ,
258806.8719 ,
249384.2299 ,
268892.842  ,
254283.2491 ,
255617.3989 ,
286175.3311 ,
258368.2129 ,
249539.6552 ,
269203.6384 ,
269755.3698 ,
269392.8287 ,
252147.676  ,
255713.1655 ,
271001.1407 ,
248391.2583 ,
240703.2801 ,
270153.9983 ,
254299.9077 ,
259155.6813 ,
253357.0665 ,
243785.4121 ,
253576.38   ,
254753.063  ,
253790.2019 ,
262081.2202 ,
258657.8911 ,
261283.9132 ,
249232.9608 ,
249158.2798 ,
257884.5534 ,
260569.0427 ,
258560.9309 ,
247903.5157 ,
242048.8927 ,
251653.2489 ,
264201.2664 ,
250332.2627 ,
249930.0874 ,
251782.7888 ,
251995.3313 ,
252072.1891 ,
247586.837  ,
255785.8282 ,
265724.5221 ,
246716.9023 ,
257153.8441 ,
263910.1098 ,
261411.6601 ,
252322.0483 ,
256283.9733 ,
264252.3402 ,
262177.6271 ,
253601.2635 ,
248097.6059 ,
264764.9703 ,
255385.5168 ,
255825.4256 ,
248645.601  ,
246317.8881 ,
242565.1    ,
259981.8484 ,
260431.3184 ,
259362.1328 ,
250522.5208 ,
251584.9667 ,
243361.1934 ,
267465.2405 ,
261173.7573 ,
243002.6667 ,
270970.1563 ,
260838.6096 ,
266262.1518 ,
257581.5629 ,
267555.719  ,
264541.4452 ,
264718.5595 ,
254959.4765 ,
257703.4726 ,
250036.4213 ,
260799.3784 ,
271084.5639 ,
263862.2794 ,
261550.9781 ,
251451.1895 ,
256262.741  ,
263623.2381 ,
258533.6659 ,
275680.6074 ,
260567.63   ,
249573.7181 ,
252143.1487 ,
278980.206  ,
247733.9005 ,
251487.1724 ,
264847.2551 ,
263236.6249 ,
254736.789  ,
261697.2945 ,
253136.6801 ,
272787.4299 ,
245562.9792 ,
266720.0346 ,
261459.981  ,
269191.5463 ,
248410.7924 ,
257020.0141 ,
253516.1283 ,
266184.5812 ,
253762.4451 ,
263628.8922 ,
259827.7755 ,
266406.5925 ,
245390.9254 ,
248703.0348 ,
266999.0458 ,
270567.3143 ,
255381.7545 ,
258463.1869 ,
256649.2156 ,
253256.7841 ,
252676.632  ,
251481.7667 ,
244238.1655 ,
255738.4571 ,
265571.9022 ,
251488.5107 ,
270887.581  ,
259307.153  ,
255012.5926 ,
255236.1976 ,
265500.9109 ,
256489.6535 ,
265275.834  ,
272031.9987 ,
267752.163  ,
250507.6371 ,
264845.6913 ,
247161.8235 ,
258955.4316 ,
269903.1894 ,
256042.2969 ,
258245.5772 ,
263731.9551 ,
258395.0897 ,
249437.7558 ,
262410.3417 ,
258121.2179 ,
266345.4141 ,
257696.6581 ,
268455.0814 ,
249202.4535 ,
262694.5553 ,
248254.9617 ,
258675.0914 ,
262705.6558 ,
253291.3194 ,
260285.1383 ,
246858.4408 ,
265485.1663 ,
250240.8784 ,
254380.6738 ,
260492.5638 ,
255384.8731 ,
255208.9861 ,
256196.4855 ,
236728.2866 ,
258667.1641 ,
255100.618  ,
256259.5153 ,
259051.1357 ,
253785.8668 ,
268147.9848 ,
259186.6906 ,
266533.2142 ,
254764.1861 ,
262710.0835 ,
258061.8491 ,
249799.2637 ,
259682.1146 ,
253467.9901 ,
241242.0222 ,
265979.9033 ,
267972.8717 ,
253558.3797 ,
259178.7942 ,
248642.4426 ,
244837.1581 ,
256506.7493 ,
248529.2731 ,
269799.8113 ,
246095.9117 ,
269844.8626 ,
257268.5155 ,
263325.3092 ,
260168.414  ,
241941.3881 ,
246181.0813 ,
255036.2313 ,
248841.6567 ,
256004.4138 ,
247562.9947 ,
273886.5466 ,
246882.2244 ,
241639.0995 ,
261420.1686 ,
255991.9299 ,
254455.4545 ,
256166.0106 ,
269247.1027 ,
248983.0942 ,
256144.7224 ,
259417.5236 ,
264686.7068 ,
258973.9191 ,
256046.202  ,
269195.5892 ,
255809.4303 ,
252585.6261 ,
249914.5971 ,
249115.541  ,
250832.7639 ,
252799.5533 ,
248404.3006 ,
258080.1087 ,
253010.1586 ,
288179.7944 ,
252298.5071 ,
268702.2057 ,
251188.7216 ,
240008.2172 ,
252685.5585 ,
263779.997  ,
258173.9946 ,
261534.0892 ,
260258.7298 ,
260468.7033 ,
259187.3989 ,
267619.3354 ,
258496.9829 ,
261833.6847 ,
254281.0612 ,
256619.6887 ,
266108.1852 ,
263670.6961 ,
262788.1618 ,
256667.4053 ,
248917.5788 ,
268799.6813 ,
260134.385  ,
253471.5677 ,
256398.7171 ,
266453.8919 ,
272114.4774 ,
261883.8199 ,
243919.349  ,
266944.3434 ,
258530.1801 ,
252005.037  ,
254991.4701 ,
256357.5061 ,
244024.573  ,
262034.1051 ,
270531.7896 ,
254845.633  ,
268421.7216 ,
260163.3436 ,
247577.7124 ,
264135.9554 ,
254695.888  ,
251569.8334 ,
267829.8829 ,
260445.4916 ,
264890.6018 ,
247594.0467 ,
247102.8926 ,
251931.9268 ,
261484.2507 ,
256829.4813 ,
261552.6519 ,
260550.6816 ,
259225.215  ,
257050.6126 ,
269501.0331 ,
248913.8014 ,
262591.3573 ,
262764.8102 ,
255642.4152 ,
247476.1877 ,
253731.6836 ,
256033.7906 ,
269225.6663 ,
259294.1256 ,
264982.3628 ,
252638.9376 ,
254775.2173 ,
273344.2062 ,
253528.7102 ,
248664.6232 ,
240673.7298 ,
244879.4116 ,
256812.0081 ,
251132.4429 ,
251638.1858 ,
246934.2115 ,
260702.6841 ,
266904.2157 ,
253569.5744 ,
249156.6654 ,
275993.2323 ,
255255.9741 ,
260757.6451 ,
274993.773  ,
267358.4871 ,
267057.8329 ,
245182.6621 ,
273576.3757 ,
248694.7806 ,
252157.0438 ,
267417.8962 ,
264089.3882 ,
259255.7702 ,
251915.9077 ,
258863.7295 ,
251853.8372 ,
260731.1039 ,
245961.4329 ,
252099.3342 ,
261379.5524 ,
265720.1445 ,
260775.8759 ,
252426.0787 ,
258240.484  ,
269192.4572 ,
252926.9091 ,
245906.5731 ,
256268.8742 ,
256010.5051 ,
251026.0302 ,
260822.1895 ,
254805.2455 ,
272914.0612 ,
260964.7788 ,
251440.5878 ,
255098.5702 ,
261263.7861 ,
244635.733  ,
243565.4597 ,
261332.3978 ,
247107.7299 ,
251985.0908 ,
268651.1244 ,
264644.3931 ,
252937.7141 ,
252139.477  ,
274798.5094 ,
262987.5819 ,
252018.7461 ,
253661.0568 ,
249928.5393 ,
280849.1813 ,
253410.4817 ,
268694.9478 ,
243772.3065 ,
261647.8908 ,
262344.8665 ,
256379.4583 ,
245514.2825 ,
248514.6049 ,
255039.0472 ,
262277.8547 ,
245464.0931 ,
261553.0948 ,
273015.0792 ,
255110.1682 ,
255952.8846 ,
266486.4459 ,
259783.2156 ,
257851.1837 ,
249960.3997 ,
247038.4772 ,
275486.9215 ,
255882.3945 ,
259487.0918 ,
255291.8383 ,
251930.2284 ,
257730.7297 ,
263260.6016 ,
239730.4861 ,
257944.8952 ,
240633.1218 ,
251978.0821 ,
268026.202  ,
254905.7107 ,
254244.6475 ,
247433.7393 ,
263032.9632 ,
258097.646  ,
252904.1084 ,
244993.0296 ,
261129.1087 ,
262895.0318 ,
259616.0463 ,
247435.2697 ,
252407.5429 ,
266227.4884 ,
264394.86   ,
264989.1163 ,
252998.8218 ,
261539.6948 ,
273368.6746 ,
260181.9255 ,
257306.3373 ,
247613.2162 ,
244100.6214 ,
234613.262  
];
  this.results[1].data = [4.5, 4, 5.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 5.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 5.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 5.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 5.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 5.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 5.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 5.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 5.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 5.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 6, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];
  this.results[2].data = [5.5, 6, 7.2, 5.1, 4.6, 7.9, 3.4, 7.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 7.4, 3, 3, 4, 7.4, 3.9, 5.5, 5.8, 5.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 7, 3.4, 8.1, 3, 6.1, 9.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];
  this.results[3].data = [4.5, 4, 5.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 5.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 5.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 5.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 5.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 5.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 5.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 5.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 5.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 7.8, 7.2, 3, 5.8, 5.6, 5.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 5.7, 6.3, 8.2, 2.8, 3, 5.8, 3, 2.8, 7.8, 8.8, 9.8, 4.6, 3, 8.4, 7.1, 8, 4.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];


  for(let i=0; i<this.results.length; i++)
    {
     let objHistogram = {
        name: this.results[i].seriesName,
        color: this.results[i].color,
        type: "histogram",
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: "s"+i,
        zIndex: -1
      }
      let objectData = {
        name: "Data" + i,
        showInLegend: false,
        data: this.results[i].data,
        id: "s"+i
      };
      this.chartSeries[2*i]=objHistogram;
      this.chartSeries[2*i+1]=objectData;
    }

  }
}
```

New jsfiddle code

```
http://jsfiddle.net/x51b6pvs/89/
```

Comment: Have you looked at adding an event callback for mouseover? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver

Comment: Any idea in how to round the data just for display

Comment: I tried the mouse over event . It does fire but unable to retrieve the range values

Comment: I have added the new jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/x51b6pvs/89/ . It getting undefined. Not sure sure if i am doing it the right way

Comment: You are getting undefined in the histogram, because your tooltip is using this `var extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();` which is to say, the 0th index axis. The histograms have yAxis index 1.

Comment: Thanks for that but i just get to figure it out that getExtremes wont giveme the range. I am looking at getting the range

Comment: You can use [tooltip.pointFormat](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bellcurve.tooltip.pointFormat) to define tooltip formatting - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/s639r5nj/1/ - if you need more control you can use pointFormatter callback. You can read about string formatting here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the tooltip formatter function :

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
             return `Rounded value is ${Math.round(this.y)}`;
        }
    },
    title : ...,
    xAxis : ...,
}
```

Documentation at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip